# References in footnote (Chicago reference style) with "ibid". and "op. cite."

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes

I Need to cite references in footnote according to Chicago reference style where "ibid". and "op. cite." will be generated automatically in latex. A sample screen-shot generated manually in MS word is attached here. Please help.

[image: Foot note citation_Chicago style]

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and [biber](http://ctan.org/pkg/biber) installed on your system, and also the package [biblatex-chicago](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago). Then add

```
\usepackage[english]{babel} %% or other supported language
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```

to your preamble.

However, you should read the [biblatex-chicago manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf)